# How to interpolate property values provided by custom PropertySource in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have my custom `FooPropertySource`s that extends `EnumerablePropertySource`. I add all of these in the `@Configuration` class to the `ConfigurableEnvironment` and they are correctly picked up be application and all the values are resolved.

However, if some values contain placeholders, they're not being interpolated. I thought I should use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to solve that problem, but it seems like this configurer is meant to deal with placeholders in beans, rather than in property sources.

So far I tried this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("foo.config.import")
open class FooConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var env: ConfigurableEnvironment;

    @Value("\${foo.config.import}")
    private lateinit var locationSpecifier: String;

    @PostConstruct
    private fun initialize() {
        val placeholderConfigurer = PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer();
        val beanFactory = DefaultListableBeanFactory();
        
        this.resolvePropertySources(this.parseLocationSpecifier())
            .forEach(this.env.propertySources::addFirst);
        placeholderConfigurer.setEnvironment(this.env);
        placeholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    }

    internal fun resolvePropertySources(path: Path): Set<FooPropertySource> {
        //...
        return ...;
    }

    internal fun parseLocationSpecifier(): Path {
        //...
        return path;
    }
}
```

Now, if an instance of `FooPropertySource` contains these properties:

```
firstname = John
lastname = Doe
fullname = ${firstname} ${lastname}
```

I'd like, in the end, when my application calls to `env.getProperty("fullname")` it will get the string `"John Doe"`, rather than `"${firstname} ${lastname}"`.

Any hopes to resolve that problem? I'm struggling with it for third day already… :-(

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @JoshC. Nope, I gave it up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create an extension function

```
fun ConfigurableEnvironment.fullname() = "${getProperty("firstname")} ${getProperty("lastname")}"
```

Comment: Those property names are just examples and they are not known upfront. It must be much more general mechanism.